# Javascript 3 functions in only one

Tags: javascript

I have make from 3 functions(newContractAction, shareGroupsAction, familyAction)  only one. I made these functions to show a menu, but I have to make only one function now. I am not advance in js so I need help from you guys.

```js
function newContractAction(actions, customerNumber, path) {
  if (actions.indexOf("newcontract") == -1) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    "index": actions.indexOf("newcontract"),
    "name": "Contract nou",
    "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/buckets.html?customerNo=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
  }
}

function shareGroupsAction(actions, customerNumber, path) {
  if (actions.indexOf("shared") == -1) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    "index": actions.indexOf("shared"),
    "name": "Configureaza Share Groups",
    "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/orangeShare.html?customerNumber=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
  }
}

function familyAction(actions, customerNumber, path) {
  if (actions.indexOf("family") == -1) {
    return null;
  }

  return {
    "index": actions.indexOf("family"),
    "name": "Configureaza Familie",
    "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/family.html?customerNumber=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
  }
}



this.customActionsCategory = function(actions, customerNumber, path) {

  var customActions = [];
  var newContract = newContractAction(actions, customerNumber, path);
  var sharedGroups = shareGroupsAction(actions, customerNumber, path);
  var family = familyAction(actions, customerNumber, path);

  if (newContract) {
    customActions.splice(newContract.index, 0, newContract);
  }
  if (sharedGroups) {
    customActions.splice(sharedGroups.index, 0, sharedGroups);
  }
  if (family) {
    customActions.splice(family.index, 0, family);
  }

  return customActions;
}
```

Where actions is an array ['newcontract', 'shared', 'family'], customerNumber is a phone number and path is a file path.
I tried to do a single function and put a switch inside with actions.indexOf() like var for switch, but doesn't work because I have to print out in the same time all items from actions array, because those items are the links name from a menu.
Someone please give me a hand.

Comment: Turn the tests around`if (actions.indexOf("newcontract") != -1) {
  return {
    "index": actions.indexOf("newcontract"), ...... else if  (actions.indexOf("shared") != -1) {  return {
    "index": actions.indexOf("shared"), ........... ....... ..... else return null`

Comment: add another parameter stating the desired action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can just add a type of action, and an object containing that type's information, like so:

```
let types = {
    "newcontract": {
        "title": "Contract nou",
        "link": "/buckets.html?customerNo="
    },
    "shared": {
        "title": "Configureaza Share Groups",
        "link": "/orangeShare.html?customerNumber="
    }
};

function action(type, actions, customerNumber, path) {
    if (actions.indexOf(type) == -1)
        return null;

    return {
        "index": actions.indexOf(type),
        "name": types[type].title,
        "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + types[type].link + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
    }
}
```

Notes:

- It is wrong to have both `customerNo` and `customerNumber`. choose one, stick to it
- You may have the wrong approach to building a menu. It should be simpler than this.

Comment: My friend I am a junior in js, believe me or not, I still learn. Probably u r right but I did it with my js level :).

Comment: @JohnSmith good luck learning. Does this function not satisfy your request?

Comment: please give me some time to test it.

Comment: please tell me if I am wrong: from what I understand I have to put the type parameter manually each time I called action function, right? actions, customerNumber, path come automatically from backend.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. All I did was unifying the first 3 functions into a single function, with a type parameter, as there is no enough context / it is assumed you can continue from there. Now, instead of your 4th function calling 3 functions, it can call only 1, however 3 times. (lack of context for unifying)

Comment: my friend I try to understand, where u set u this link for types[type].link ?

Comment: the `types` variable holds the link for each type, and the title (or name) for each type. When you do types[type] it finds the correct object reference, and then a ".link" is just to get the link property.

Answer (score 0):

You can inverse and merge your if into else/if

```
function action(actions, customerNumber, path){
      if(actions.indexOf("newcontract") !== -1){
        return {
          "index": actions.indexOf("newcontract"),
          "name": "Contract nou",
          "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/buckets.html?customerNo=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
        }
      }else if(actions.indexOf("shared") !== -1){
        return {
          "index": actions.indexOf("shared"),
          "name": "Configureaza Share Groups",
          "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/orangeShare.html?customerNumber=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
        }
      }else if(actions.indexOf("family") !== -1){
        return {
          "index": actions.indexOf("family"),
          "name": "Configureaza Familie",
          "actionLink": SMARTSALES_CONTEXT_PATH + "/family.html?customerNumber=" + customerNumber + generateReturnUrl(path)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just saying... :)